# Login form db check error

Tags: php

Hi i need help to make a login check thourght db working anyone can say to me where is the error?
This is the code

```
if (!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
$user=stripslashes(trim($_POST['user']));
$password=stripslashes(trim($_POST['password']));
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("project");
$check=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE nome='$user' AND password='$password'");
if(mysql_num_rows($check)!0)
{
$details=mysql_fetch_array($check);
$_SESSION['display_name']=$details[0];
$_SESSION['username']=$details[1];
$_SESSION['password']=$details[2];
print "Login succesful. <p>  Level access: " . $details["type"] ;
}
else
{
print "Error";
}
}
else
{
print "Not all fields are compiled" ;
}

if ($details["type"] == "admin" )
{
    $admn = 1;
}
else
{
    $admn = 0;
}
```

I've no clue why is not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and no longer supported.  Update to `mysqli_` or PDO

Comment: `(mysql_num_rows($check)!0)` shouldn't be `(mysql_num_rows($check) != 0)`?

Comment: Also, you should use prepared statements, as your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Why are you using `stripslashes`? Don't pass user input direct to SQL. Don't store passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`if(mysql_num_rows($check)!0)`

To This:

`if(mysql_num_rows($check) != 0)`